# (OFF Line MAP) how to download osm tiles to use OFF LINE MAP in react-native-maps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, maps, openstreetmap, react-native-maps

Respected sir/ma'am I want to implement offline osm map in my project. but i don't found any proper documentation for how to download tiles for offline usage. i am currently using react-native-maps package for implementing custom Tile Overlay

```
import { LocalTile } from 'react-native-maps';

<MapView
  region={this.state.region}
  onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
>
  <LocalTile
   /**
    * The path template of the locally stored tiles. The patterns {x} {y} {z} will be replaced at runtime
    * For example, /storage/emulated/0/mytiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
    */
   pathTemplate={this.state.pathTemplate}
   /**
    * The size of provided local tiles (usually 256 or 512).
    */
   tileSize={256}
  />
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward approach for downloading offline *raster* tiles for OSM. Rendering these tiles is very resource intensive and depending on the zoom level the download and storage size of raster tiles will become huge. In other words: raster tiles should be avoided for offline use. You should consider using [vector tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles) instead.

Possible solutions:

- [Render](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) your own *raster* tiles, for example by using [Maperitive](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive)
- Switch to a library supporting *vector* tiles and download them, for example from [OpenMapTiles.com](https://openmaptiles.com)